# JTextField and F10 key - how to remove key binding?

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

I'm trying to remove <kbd>F10</kbd> button key binding from `JTextField`, but nothing is working below:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED), "none");
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED), "none");
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED), "none");
```

Actually, I want to control popup menu  - show/hide, but <kbd>F10</kbd> not working correctly - it is performing some other actions. If I switch for example to <kbd>F11</kbd>, everything works fine.

As I know - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> shows popup on various platforms.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by _but F10 not working correctly_ - it shows the popup as is to be expected (at least in win, don't know other OSs), so what _do_ you expect?

Comment: My popup is simple JWindow, and if F10 is used - very strange behavour - popup buttons sometimes not receiving MouseEvents (they should fade in/out). And one more thing - when I press F10 when mouse is over JTextField - field lost and again get's focus.

Comment: Have you tried some of the other conditions, for example `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED)`?

Comment: hmm, why do you want to show a "fake" popup (a manually coded window) vs the default (best: component) popupMenu? Anyway, sounds like there might be something wrong in your custom code - please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int, int)` isn't used to get the `KeyStroke` for a press or release event, it is used to apply a modifier to the `KeyStroke` in the form of `KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` and/or `KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK` and/or `KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK` and/or `KeyEvent.ALT_GRAPH_DOWN_MASK` and/or `KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK`...

Instead of `getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED), "none");` you should be using `getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0), "none");`

When I use the following, I can get the key action to trigger when the field is focused...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTextFieldKeyStroke {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextFieldKeyStroke();
    }

    public TestTextFieldKeyStroke() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
            add(field);
            JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();

            field.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0), "happy");
            field.getActionMap().put("happy", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Happy");
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**Updated with popup**

I'm still missing something here, based on the previous example, if I do something like...

```
final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
add(field);
JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
pop.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
field.setComponentPopupMenu(pop);

field.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0), "happy");
field.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "happy");
field.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), "happy");
field.getActionMap().put("happy", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JPopupMenu popup = field.getComponentPopupMenu();
        popup.show(field, 0, field.getHeight());
    }
});
```

I can get it to show the `JPopupMenu`

[image]

Comment: But how can I remove existing actions for F10, SHIFT+F10 and CTRL+F10? I have described the problem below.

Comment: `F10` is system key stroke used by the accessibility API to focus the menu bar...apparently...

Comment: Do you to remove it globally or just for the field?  If I assign the key stroke to the field, I can show a popup without issue.  You should also understand that many uses will expect F10 to perform a specific action, this is not just restricted to Java but the OS as a whole...

Comment: I want to remove it just for the field.

Comment: The keystroke is begin picked up somewhere else in the system, without the associated `Action`, the key bindings API is not consuming the event, allowing it to be furthre processed.  `F10` is not a key stroke associated with the text field, therefore, simply putting an entry in the `InputMap` isn't enough

Comment: I have changed my code - previously popup window was controlled from `KeyListener`, but now moved control code to key binding `ActionListener` - now seems that all working fine. Thanks for help indeed :)

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this and it's working:

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0), "doNothing");
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK), "doNothing");
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "doNothing");

        getActionMap().put("doNothing", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        });
```

Now <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> events are removed. But if I skip `getActionMap().put("doNothing", new AbstractAction() {})`, then key bindings above not working.., but it seems that somewhere some action is still attached - cursor is changing (from `Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR` to `Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR` and again backs to `Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR`) when I press on those buttons (should do nothing). I've tried `textField.getActionMap().size()` but it return 0. So I suppose action is attached to some other component. Is it possible to find out it?

EDIT:

Here [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) I found all the answers... :)

Comment: this doesn't make much sense without context - you are _still_ not explaining _why_ you want to fight the framework ...

Comment: Because I'm using my popup menu (custom built, extends `JWindow`), and predefined F10 action do not allow to function it normally. I have to disable all F10 events.

Comment: _I have to disable all F10_ no, most probably you are doing something wrong in the code you are not showing

Comment: I think I moving to point when I will create my own TextField, like I did with ComboBox, where I have now full control, also different ScrollBar - custom made, all extends just JComponents, JWindows, JPanels..

Comment: @kleopatra Just try to put JTextField on panel, and click F10 repeatedly - and see how Cursor behaves.

Comment: right, cup of patience overflowed :-), please whats goal, maybe there are another 2-3 (more than confortable) ways, whats wrong something with document and its listeners

Comment: [Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268248-f10-blocks-other-action-keys/) is more info on this issue. So not me alone was trying to find out what's going on with F10.